# What is the use of Enumerations in Hashtables or maps?

Tags: java, hashmap, hashtable, enumeration

I was Looking for some examples of Hashtables on Stack Overflow, and found this:

```
Enumeration enumeration = companies.elements();

while ( enumeration.hasMoreElements() ) {
   System.out.println("hashtable values: "+enumeration.nextElement());
}
```

Why do we use Enumerations and specifically in Hashtables what is its significance?

Comment: If you're writing new code, don't use either, as they're obsolete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enumerations are basically an old form of the `Iterator`s. Basically, they allow you to go through a collection and get all its elements individually.

The reason that we do this is that for `HashTable`, `HashMap`, `HashSet`, `LinkedList` and more, you can't access elements efficiently by index. In fact, in the first three cases, indices have no meaning. An iterator or enumeration can therefore be used to loop through the elements to access them.

As chrylis mentioned in comments, please don't use `Enumeration`s. `Iterator`s are newer and have some special syntactic features like the enhanced `for` loop.